# como migrar php 5.6 a php 7.1

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy intentando cambiar la versión de 5.6 a 7.1 pero al momento de hacer el cambio a 7.1 me genera error y realmente no sé, ya he revisado la documentación pero no he entendido mucho, si me pudieran dar una buena explicación se los agradecería mucho gracias!!

Aquí tengo dudas ya que leí documentación pero me cuesta entender que cambios hay que hacer:

```
require("DBconection.php");
class COL_Query{


function COL_Query(){}
/*----------  consulta para la pestaña de clasificadas  ----------*/
function SQL_TableData($is_ver, $is_tip, $is_isn, $is_ciu, $is_sec, $is_car, $is_cat, $is_vin, $is_dep, $is_rev,$is_tab){

    $DBobj = new DBOptions();
    $DBobj->DB_conectar();
    $DBobj->DB_Charset();

    $sql = "Select Pos,SRG, r.Url_1, Url_2, Url_3,Url_4, Revistas, Edita, r.Ciudad, Vinculada,
    Categoria,Px,ICDS, m.Logo from Rev_sapiens r LEFT JOIN U_micro m on m.ID=r.Url_1 ";

    /*----------  en caso de haber datos se filtra ----------*/
    $sql.= "where Version like '%".$is_ver."%' ";
    $sql.= "and r.Tipo like '%".$is_tip."%' ";
    $sql.= "and ISSN like '%".$is_isn."%' ";
    $sql.= "and r.Ciudad like '%".$is_ciu."%' ";
    $sql.= "and Sector like '%".$is_sec."%' ";
    $sql.= "and Caracter like '%".$is_car."%' ";
    $sql.= "and Categoria like '%".$is_cat."%' ";
    $sql.= "and Vinculada like '%".$is_vin."%' ";
    $sql.= "and Departamento like '%".$is_dep."%' ";
    
    if ($is_rev != "") {
        $sql.= "and (Edita like '%".$is_rev."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Revistas like '%".$is_rev."%' )";
        
    }else if ($is_tab != "") {
        $sql.= "and (Version like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or r.Tipo like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or ISSN like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or r.Ciudad like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Edita like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Sector like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Revistas like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Caracter like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or r.Categoria like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Vinculada like '%".$is_tab."%' ";
        $sql.= "or Departamento like '%".$is_tab."%' )";
    }


    $order['0'] = 'Pos';
    $order['1'] = 'Categoria';
    $order['2'] = 'SRG';
    $order['5'] = 'Px';
    $order['6'] = 'ICDS';
    
    /*----------  orden de filtro  ----------*/
    if (isset($_POST["order"])) {
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY '.$order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].'  ';
    }else{
        $sql .= 'ORDER BY Version DESC, r.ID ASC  ';
    }

    /*----------  limite de paginacion  ----------*/
    $sql3 = "";
    if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
        $sql3 .= 'LIMIT '.$_POST['start']. ', '. $_POST['length'];
    }

    /*----------  llamo mi clase para la consulta  ----------*/
    $pst = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql); 
    /*----------  num resultados  ----------*/      
    $rownum = $pst->num_rows;
    /*----------  nuevamente pero ahora con limitando resultados  ----------*/
    $pst = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql.$sql3);

    $rst = array();

    /*----------  guardo los resultados en el arreglo  ----------*/

    while ($row = $pst->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rst2 = array();
        
        if ($row['Vinculada'] == 'Sí') {
            $rst2[] = '<span class="Fvincu">'.$row['Pos'].'</span><span class="social"><a target="_blank" class="social-button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php"><img src="img/facebookicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a class="social-button" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php"><img src="img/googleplusicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a class="social-button" target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php&title= ?"><img src="img/linkedinicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a target="_blank" class="social-button" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php&text=""><img src="img/twittericon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a></span>';
            $sql2 = '<span>'.$row['Categoria'].'</span>';
            $sql3='<span>'.explode(".", $row['SRG'])[0].((isset(explode(".", $row['SRG'])[1])) ? ','.explode(".", $row['SRG'])[1] : '').'</span>';
            $sql4='<div class="botons"><span class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 0;vertical-align:middle!important;"><a href="'.$row['Url_2'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['Revistas'].'</a> - <a href="universidad/'.$row['Url_1'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['Edita'].'</a></span>';
                $sql4 .='<span  class="col-xs-2" style="padding: 0; align-items:center;" >';
                $sql4 .='<a class="btn btn-primary perfil"
                href="https://www.srg.com.co/universidad/'.$row['Url_1'].'" 
                target="_blank" style="background:white;"><img alt="Logo'. $row["Url_1"] .'" src="img/micrositios/'.$row["Logo"].'"></a></span></div>';
            $sql5='<span>'.$row['Ciudad'].'</span>';
            

        }else{
            $rst2[] = '<span>'.$row['Pos'].'</span><span class="social"><a target="_blank" class="social-button" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php"><img src="img/facebookicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a class="social-button" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php"><img src="img/googleplusicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a class="social-button" target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php&title= ?"><img src="img/linkedinicon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a><a target="_blank" class="social-button" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.srg.com.co/revsapiens.php&text=""><img src="img/twittericon.png" width="32px"  height="32px"/></a></span>';
            $sql2 = '<span>'.$row['Categoria'].'</span>';
            $sql3='<span>'.explode(".", $row['SRG'])[0].((isset(explode(".", $row['SRG'])[1])) ? ','.explode(".", $row['SRG'])[1] : '').'</span>';
            $sql4='<span class="col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 0;vertical-align:middle!important;"><a href="'.$row['Url_2'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['Revistas'].'</a> - '.$row['Edita'].'</span>';
            $sql5='<span>'.$row['Ciudad'].'</span>';
            
        }
        $sql6='<span><a href="'.$row['Url_4'].'" target="_blank">'.explode(".", $row['Px'])[0].((isset(explode(".", $row['Px'])[1])) ? ','.explode(".", $row['Px'])[1] : '').'</a></span>';
        $sql7='<span><a href="'.$row['Url_3'].'" target="_blank">'.explode(".", $row['ICDS'])[0].((isset(explode(".", $row['ICDS'])[1])) ? ','.explode(".", $row['ICDS'])[1] : '').'</a></span>';
        
        $rst2[] = $sql2;
        $rst2[] = $sql3;
        $rst2[] = $sql4;
        $rst2[] = $sql5;
        $rst2[] = $sql6;
        $rst2[] = $sql7;

        $rst[] = $rst2;

    }

    /*----------  cuento los resultados totales para el mensaje  ----------*/

    function get_all_data($DBobj){
        $pst = $DBobj->DB_SQL("SELECT ID FROM Rev_sapiens");
        return $pst->num_rows;
    }



    /*----------  preparo la respuesta json  ----------*/
    $output = array(
        "draw" =>         intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal" => get_all_data($DBobj),
        "recordsFiltered" => $rownum, 
        "data" =>  $rst

    );

    /*----------  retorno la respuesta   ----------*/
    $DBobj->DB_cerrar();
    return $output;

}


function COL_City(){
    $DBobj = new DBOptions();
    $DBobj->DB_conectar();
    $DBobj->DB_Charset();
    $drp = array();

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Version from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Version DESC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ISSN from Rev_sapiens";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Ciudad from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Ciudad ASC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Departamento from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Departamento ASC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);
    
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Tipo from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Tipo ASC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);
    
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Sector from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Sector ASC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);
    
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Caracter from Rev_sapiens ORDER BY Caracter ASC";
    $drp[] = $DBobj->DB_SQL($sql);
    
    

    return  $drp;
}`

require("COL_Query_Revsapiens.php");
$tmp = new COL_Query();
if (isset($act)) {

{$pst = $tmp->COL_City();};
$SEL_ver = "";
$SEL_issn = "";
$SEL_ciu = "";
$SEL_dep = "";
$SEL_tip = "";
$SEL_sec = "";
$SEL_car = "";

while($rst=$pst[0]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_ver .=  "<option value='".$rst['Version']."'>".$rst['Version']."</option>";
}
while($rst = $pst[1]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_issn .=  "<option value='".$rst['ISSN']."'>".$rst['ISSN']."</option>";
}
while($rst = $pst[2]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_ciu .=  "<option value='".$rst['Ciudad']."'>".$rst['Ciudad']."</option>";
}
while($rst = $pst[3]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_dep .=  "<option value='".$rst['Departamento']."'>".$rst['Departamento']."</option>";
}

while($rst = $pst[4]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_tip .=  "<option value='".$rst['Tipo']."'>".$rst['Tipo']."</option>";
}

while($rst = $pst[5]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_sec .=  "<option value='".$rst['Sector']."'>".ucwords(strtolower($rst['Sector']))."</option>";
}

while($rst = $pst[6]->fetch_assoc()){
    $SEL_car .=  "<option value='".$rst['Caracter']."'>".ucwords(strtolower($rst['Caracter']))."</option>";
}

}



if(isset($_GET["act"])){

/*----------  llamo la clase de la consulta, y luego atrapo el resultado y lo codifico para imprimirlo despues  ----------*/
{$RST = $tmp->SQL_TableData($_POST["is_ver"], $_POST["is_tip"], $_POST["is_isn"], $_POST["is_ciu"], $_POST["is_sec"], $_POST["is_car"],  $_POST["is_cat"], $_POST["is_vin"], $_POST["is_dep"], $_POST["is_rev"],$_POST["is_tab"] );};
echo json_encode($RST);
}
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: siii lo que pasa es que no le llegan los datos al datatables pero la consulta esta bien realmente no se lo que es   DataTables warning: table id=vincu - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: El error en la pregunta por favor.. y donde se devuelve el json que recibe tu datatable? porque el error habla sobre eso... verificaste que el json sea correcto?

Comment: Un warning no es un error. Por favor, edita tu pregunta, le añades el error que encuentras, lo que debería hacer el script y lo que está haciendo en su lugar. Recuerda que ahora mismo sólo tú sabes toda esta info

Comment: Puede que tu código necesite una revisión profunda, por ejemplo, tienes un montón de punteros hacia los datos abiertos al mismo tiempo en esos `while` al final que dan muy mala impresión. No sé lo que quieres hacer, pero quizá haya que pensar en unir tablas para traer un sólo conjunto de resultados y no varios... De todos modos, como dicen los compañeros, conviene que pulses en [edit]  poniendo los errores que estás teniendo. Si estás migrando el código y usas viejas APIs de conexión, puede que el problema actual esté en la clase que usas para conectar a la base de datos.